# How to embed Facebook like box widget for group (+ USER POST STEAM )

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-group

EX :

http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=144375998956146&width=250&connections=8&stream=true&header=true&height=700

I need to steam normal user posts too...

but this demo steaming only "Group user"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create api from

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

and look in real live box